# Nesting php-file

Tags: php, recursion, nested

My first entry so be kind.

I'm trying to nest a php-file, please don't ask why, and I have tried with include, include_once, require, require_once, and shell_exec.

I only get
"Do this first, and finish with this."

I would like to get, (as a recursive call)
"Do this first, do this second, and finish with this."

My test_include.php

```
<?php

$debug = ($_REQUEST['debug']);

if($debug == "")
{
    echo "Do this first, ";

    include_once("test_include.php?debug=True");
}

if($debug == "True") echo " do this second, ";

if($debug == "") echo "and finish with this.";

?>
```

Comment: Then what does `$debug` actually contains?

Comment: In first call Nothing, but in the include-call it contains "True"

Comment: I'm wondering how that works, because include does not do a HTTP request, it's a file include... for which you usually can't pass any GET parameters.

Comment: Exactly, so what I could do is to set the debug and then include, or? But the I wouldn't get the desired output.... I would only get "Do this first, do this second, "

Comment: So the question is, how to execute the script as a new instance.